# React Native App Crashes on Pixel Physical Device Without Any Error or Crash Logs

Tags: react-native, pixel

I am currently facing a weired issue after upgrading to React Native 0.66.4 which causes my Android app to crash on Pixel Mobile Devices after release.

I am however able to run the app in both debug and release modes on any Pixel simulator targeting API 30 or 31.

There is absolutey no error or crash log neither in Logcat nor on Google Play Console.

When I tap on the app's icon, it crashes instantly without even lauching the initial activity of the app.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the cause of that issue. There was actually a crash line in the app's Logcat as:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.xyz.app: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent
```

I fixed that by adding the following package:

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue when I updated my app to 0.66.4, my issue was that I was not using Linking of react-native package correctly.

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', this.openUrl);

const openUrl = async () => {
 ...
}
```

In my above code, the **openUrl** is an async function which was causing the issue. Removing the async resolved the issue.

```
const openUrl = () => {
     ...
}
```

Comment: But the issue you’ve mentioned has not been probably causing the app to fail during its initial launch. Has it? My issue is that the app cannot be opened at all and even the initial component is not being executed.

Comment: Can you check the logs till where is it going? Whether its atleast opening App.js?